# Probability that one random variable is greater than another

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Suppose I have two random variables:

```
Control = BetaDistribution[24,141]
Var = BetaDistribution[30,151]
```

I can sample from this easy enough with `RandomVariate[Var, 10]`  and calculate the probability that one of the distributions is greater than a constant, e.g. `Probability[x <= .2, x \[Distributed] Var]`.

But how do I calculate $P(Var>Control)$. Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very similar:

```
Probability[
 control < var, {control \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[24, 141], 
  var \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[30, 151]}]
```

1191614106688032995829016253297371 / 1700223091652404809206230640390474

(roughly 0.7)

Verify numerically:

```
control = BetaDistribution[24, 141]
var = BetaDistribution[30, 151]
Count[Thread[
  RandomVariate[control, 1000000] < 
   RandomVariate[var, 1000000]], True]
```

also roughly 0.7

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. One more question. How would I do it with a declared variable -- I'm not sure on the syntax there, e.g. something like:

`Control = BetaDistribution[24,141]; Var = BetaDistribution[30,151]; Probability[Control < Var, {Control, Var}]`

Comment: ```control = BetaDistribution[24, 141];
var = BetaDistribution[30, 151];
Probability[c < v, {c \[Distributed] control, v \[Distributed] var}]```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!